# how can i make a blackberry app that can fit to almost all the devices

Tags: blackberry, java-me

how can i make a blackberry app that can fit to almost all the devices having different screen resolutions.

i mean the look wise mostly alignment of components in device. Is there any standard procedure for this like in android

Comment: "i mean the look wise mostly alignment of components in device." - so what is ment here? I can't parse this.. :)

Comment: in one device alignment is good, and in some other its not aligned properly

Comment: Probably it would be better for you to provide a sample code with screenshots of a problem, otherwise the responses maybe too vague. If compare with Android, then Android provides 9-patch images and they do simplify the matter a lot. BB does not have this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending sometime trying to figure out the easiest method to get our application looking good across all devices, I ended up following the Android model.

The application has three folders:

- /res/**hdpi** (240x)
- /res/**mdpi** (320x)
- /res/**ldpi** (480x)

I have basic utility class thats something like this:

```
public class DisplayUtils {
    public static float density = DisplayUtils.getDensity();

    private static float getDensity() {
        float dpi = (Display.getHorizontalResolution() * 0.0254f);
        if (dpi <= 135.0f) {
            return 0.75f;
        } else if (dpi <= 200.0f) {
            return 1.0f;
        } else {
            return 1.5f;
        }
    }

    public static int convertPxToDp(int px) {
        return (int) (px * DisplayUtils.density + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

The entire application aligns everything up relative to other elements so it looks good overall. The biggest issue is Storm/Torch will look a little bit small due to being considered MDPI instead of HDPI. This should at least give you a good start.

Answer (score 2):

try setting the positions in relative manner like :

position of button placed next to a label must have position relative to the button, 
try using custom managers for this purpose.

but this is not perfect in each case depending upon the graphics u use.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a lot of time on this subject. The best and easiest idea in my mind is to "make" all of your graphics using the BlackBerry graphics API's. Then, all of your fields will easily shrink and expand based on the different device resolution.

You could always have three different sets of graphics (each designed for a different resolution), also. This is a lot of work in my mind.